# Spring CorsFilter does not seem to work still receiving a 401 on preflight requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors

Hi I'm new to spring security and trying to figure out how to configure auth server to issue tokens. the problem i have right now is that I'm receiving 401 or 403 on the Cors preflight requests and not sure how to resolve below is a barebone implementation of it based on few tutorials

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:oauth.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        super.configure(web);
    }

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }




    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
        withUser("john").password("123").roles("USER").
        and().
        withUser("tom").password("111").roles("ADMIN");

    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter2());
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }


}


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2ServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer){
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{
        clients.inMemory().withClient("acme").secret("acmesecret").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                  "password").scopes("openId");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints){
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(),accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                 .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                 .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter(){
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(){

        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());

    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter2());
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

the CorsFilter2 is spring cors filter that was introduced in spring 4.2 I was i'm using it to insert the proper response headers to send back to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what my problem I had to configure my websecurity to ignore CoresRequest request as well so inside the configure block for the websecurity i had to set this

```
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest);
```

and it started to work.

Comment: Hey man where did you configured it, i get: ´´´The method ignoring() is undefined for the type ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry´´´ if i set it after ´´´authorizeRequests´´´ and ´´´The method ignoring() is undefined for the type HttpSecurity´´´´ direclty after http

Comment: @mattobob I added it to the configure method in my SecurityConfig  the method signature should look something like this 
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {}